# Any explanation for this interesting property of a Napoleon triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811800/interesting-property-about-triangles-i-dont-know-about) Jose discovered that the length between the vertex of any non equilateral triangle and the associated vertex of an equilateral triangle constructed on the same base opposite the vertex, is the same length, for all the vertices of the triangle. For lack of a better name let's call this length the Jose length of the triangle.

While playing around with this curiosity in Geogebra I discovered this length appears to be always equal to any side length of the [inner Napolean triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerNapoleonTriangle.html) multiplied by $ \sqrt{3} \ $. Can anyone show why that is always the case and why the factor of $\sqrt{3} \ $? [A Geogebra construction demonstrating this is here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/gbkfdrsm). The red segments are the Jose lengths and the green triangle is the inner Napolean triangle.

Edit: As an aside, there is another interesting relationship between the Jose lengths and inner Napolean triangle. If perpendicular bisectors are constructed on the Jose segments, a new triangle is defined, which is congruent to the the inner Napolean triangle, but "orbits" around the outside of the triangle. [The Geogebra construction is here.](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/dvhxywrb)  I think this construction basically demonstrates that the Jose segments are always perpendicular to a corresponding side of the inner Napolean triangle. Its hard to tell if it is effectively a rotation or a reflection of the inner Napolean triangle or both. As the parent triangle more closely approaches being an equilateral triangle the orbital triangle more closely approaches being a point on the circumcircle of the parent triangle and when the parent triangle is exactly an equilateral triangle the location of the point is not precisely defined and appears almost random.

Comment: Calvin Lin's comment to the original question observes that the equality of any two of the "Jose lengths" follows by pivoting a particular triangle by 60∘ about a vertex (say, $A$). For your question, observe that connecting $A$ to the neighboring "inner Napoleon" vertices creates a triangle similar to that pivoting triangle, with a readily-determined scale factor. (BTW: These arguments work for both the "inner" and "outer" Napoleon configurations. Indeed, these arguments effectively constitute a *proof* of the "inner" and "outer" Napoleon theorems.)

Comment: @Blue I've added another observation you might be interested in.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I'll fix that.

Comment: The Napoleon configuration is chock-full of interesting properties. :)  You can find a few at [Cut-the-Knot](https://cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/NapoleonProperties.shtml). ... Regarding perpendicularity: We "know" that the three Jose segments meet at a Napoleon point, $N$; the side-lines of the Napoleon triangle are the corresponding perpendicular bisectors of $AN$, $BN$, $CN$ (which are sub-segments of the Jose segments).

Comment: BTW: Your neat orbiting triangle is "random" for nearly-equilateral $\triangle ABC$ because the Jose segments become very short, and thus also become very sensitive to changes made by even small cursor motions. For more control, try this: In your GeoGebra figure, $\triangle FBC$ is equilateral. Draw a line through $F$, and constrain $A$ to it. Then, moving $A$ towards $F$ along the line, $\triangle ABC$ becomes equilateral, and your orbiting triangle shrinks to a *particular* point that seems to depend very nicely upon the line and the circumcircle.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit like those discontinuous functions where the limit depends on which direction it is approached from.